# Initiate Masonry - After infinite scroll and parametric search

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, pagination

Having a problem with AJAX and [Masonry grid](http://masonry.desandro.com/). Masonry grid is simple not being initiated at the right moments.

Before scrolling or using the parametric search to go to a specific category, it works very well.

Sample site can be found [here](http://www.unicornart.no/kunst/).

---

## Masonry

Masonry is a JavaScript grid layout library. Used normally with Bootstrap or another grid system that does not align the items correctly. Example:

#### Only bootstrap:

[image: With only Bootstrap]

#### Bootstrap and Masonry:

[image: With Bootstrap and Masonry]

---

## When scrolling

The next columns are being added above the older ones. Giving almost the same output as [unloaded images](http://masonry.desandro.com/faq.html) which makes images overlapping. This is normally solved by using `imagesLoaded` which I have already included in the provided code.

[image: After scroll]

### When using parametric search

The Masonry is not being fired after the AJAX. Meaning it does not work at all. So the columns are being loaded without Masonry.

Please see [sample site](http://www.unicornart.no/kunst/).

[image: When using parametric search]

---

Both scrolling and parametric search is delivered by [Toolset](https://wp-types.com). They have a good system with making it very easy to load JS at specific times:

- After the [AJAX Pagination with Toolset](https://wp-types.com/documentation/user-guides/views-pagination/) has been completed.
- When parametric search has been triggered.
- When the parametric search data has been collected.
- When the parametric search form has been updated.
- When the parametric search results have been updated.

So both after pagination and before/during/after [Parametric search](https://wp-types.com/documentation/user-guides/front-page-filters/). Since the problem is after scrolling, and after the results for Parametric search has been updated, I would like to initiate the Masonry grid at this very moment.

The easiest example is when the scrolling is done, or pagination as it's also called.

## What I have tried

I used `reloadItems` as I guessed would be correct. Please correct me if I am wrong. [Resource](http://masonry.desandro.com/methods.html).

```
jQuery( document ).on( 'js_event_wpv_pagination_completed', function( event, data ) {
  $container.masonry('reloadItems')
});
```

In my theory it would reload all the items when scrolling, so they would be arranged properly. But it changes nothing.

I have also tried the following:

```
jQuery( document ).on( 'js_event_wpv_pagination_completed', function( event, data ) {
  var $container = $('.masonry-container');        
        $container.imagesLoaded(function() {               
            $container.masonry('reload');
            $container.masonry({
                isInitLayout : true,
                itemSelector: '.col-md-3'
            });
        });
  //and on ajax  call append or prepend
$container.prepend($data).imagesLoaded(function(){
    $container.masonry( 'prepended', $data, true );
}); 
});
```

I also tried to reload the items when the parametric search results has been updated.

```
jQuery( document ).on( 'js_event_wpv_parametric_search_results_updated', function( event, data ) {
     $container.masonry('reloadItems')  
});
```

But this did not work either.

The Masonry is also added in the footer by using one of the methodes.

```
(function( $ ) {
    "use strict";
    var $container = $('.masonry-container');
    $container.imagesLoaded( function () {
        $container.masonry({
            columnWidth: '.col-md-3',
            percentPosition: true,
            itemSelector: '.col-md-3'
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Do you have any ideas? Where am I doing wrong?

---

## Edit 1:

### Console Error

When loading the page

> Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined

When scrolling

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $container is not defined

### Changed the function to the following

```
  (function( $ ) {
    // Initiate Masonry
    "use strict";
    var $container = $('.masonry-container');
    $container.imagesLoaded( function () {
        $container.masonry({
            columnWidth: '.item',
            percentPosition: true,
            itemSelector: '.item',
            isAnimated: true // the animated makes the process smooth
        });
    });
    $(window).resize(function() {
        $('.masonry-container').masonry({
            itemSelector: '.item',
            isAnimated: true
        }, 'reload');
    });

})(jQuery);

//and on ajax  call append or prepend more items
var $data = $(data).filter(".item");   
$container.prepend($data).imagesLoaded(function(){
    $container.masonry( 'prepended', $data, true );
});
```

### Updated imagesloaded to newest version

I also updated imagesloaded to the newest version.

Script can be found [here](http://www.unicornart.no/wp-content/themes/unicornart/js/imagesloaded.js).

### Added `.item`

I added the class `.item` instead of using col-md-3, as I thought it would be a better solution.

Meaning the HTML is the following right now:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="masonry-container">
      <div class="item">
         <!-- Content comes here -->
      </div>
      <div class="item">
         <!-- Content comes here -->
      </div>
      <div class="item">
         <!-- Content comes here -->
      </div>
      <div class="item">
         <!-- Content comes here -->
      </div>
      ...
   </div>
</div>
```

And so on.

Still console errors.

Any solutions?

Comment: could you please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ or similar to help diagnose this issue. editing your js is very difficult when it exists only on a live space

Comment: Was not possible to add the pagination from WP Types into jsfiddle. But the problem was solved by using the code below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by removing some of the duplication and so on.

Then using the following:

```
(function( $ ) {
    "use strict";
    var $container = $('.masonry-container');
    $container.imagesLoaded( function () {
        $container.masonry({
          columnWidth: '.item',
          percentPosition: true,
          itemSelector: '.item'
        });
    });

    $( document ).on( 'js_event_wpv_pagination_completed', function( event, data ) {
        $container.masonry('reloadItems').masonry();
    });

    $( document ).on( 'js_event_wpv_parametric_search_results_updated', function( event, data ) {
        $container.masonry('reloadItems').masonry();    
    });

    $( document ).on( 'js_event_wpv_pagination_completed', function( event, data ) {
        $container.masonry('reloadItems').masonry();
        $container.imagesLoaded( function() {
          $container.masonry();
        });
    });

    $( document ).on( 'js_event_wpv_parametric_search_results_updated', function( event, data ) {
        $container.masonry('reloadItems').masonry();
        $container.imagesLoaded( function() {
          $container.masonry();
        });
    });

})(jQuery);
```

This was added in the footer.php.